# Filter csv file without using panda or csv module PYTHON

Tags: python, csv

Without using any modules (panda, csv, etc) I need to filter this csv file (https://data.world/prasert/rotten-tomatoes-top-movies-by-genre/workspace/file?filename=rotten_tomatoes_top_movies_2019-01-15.csv), I would like to filter through ONLY the movies that are in the animation genre and drop the other movies. 
I have used open, split and the for loop to read the data, but I am struggling to filter the movies into genres. 
I have created a list called genres, and then appended it with genres.append(line.split(",") [4]), but this only gives a list of genres from the genre column rather than giving me info of each movie in a particular genre. 
I know it is crazy to attempt this without the modules(this is for school), but is it even possible to do this without them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like an assignment problem with suspicious restrictions of not using external libraries. This is not an assignment completion site. Please post a specific qn after you have tried it yourself

Comment: This isnt an assignment question. I have attempted to figure this out, but i suppose the specific question is how to filter rows by column values without using any modules such as panda or csv.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
f = open("file_name", "r",encoding="utf-8")
new_list=[]
header=0
for line in  f.readlines():
    #if header is present in the file
    if header==0:
        new_list.append(line)
        header=1
        continue
    #add Genre Name to filter
    if line.split(',')[4]=='genre_name':
        new_list.append(line)

#writing filtered list to output file.
out_flie=open('output.txt','w',encoding="utf-8")
for element in new_list:
    out_flie.write(element)
    out_flie.write('\n')
out_flie.close()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked perfect for me